# Java Selenium Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code:

```
click(By.id("job-description-help"), MOUSE_LEFT, 2);
click(By.id("job-description-help"), MOUSE_LEFT, 2);
click(By.id("title"), MOUSE_LEFT, 2);
sendKeys(By.id("title"), "ttttt", true, 4);
click(By.xpath(".//*[@id='editor']/span[5]/a[1]"), MOUSE_LEFT, 7);

    public void click(By locator, int mouseButton, String combinedControlKeys, int timeoutInSeconds) throws Exception {
    Boolean success = false;
    long timeoutInMillies = timeoutInSeconds * 1000;
    WebElement elm = null;
    // indicate whether the element is an <option> tag on Firefox browser
    Boolean isOptionTagOnFireFox = false;
    // time spent counters
    long timeSpentInMillis = 0;
    // try to click on the element until wait timout reached
    while ((success == false) && (timeSpentInMillis <= timeoutInMillies)) {
      try {
        // find the element and calculate time spent
        long startFinding = System.currentTimeMillis();
        elm = findElement(locator, 1);
        timeSpentInMillis += System.currentTimeMillis() - startFinding;

        if (elm != null) {
          // get tag name of the element
          String tag = elm.getTagName();
          // check whether the element is <option> tag on Firefox browser
          isOptionTagOnFireFox = isFirefoxDriver && (0 == elm.getTagName().compareToIgnoreCase("option"));

          // press control keys (Ctrl, Alt, Shift, Meta), if any
          pressControlKeys(combinedControlKeys);
          if (mouseButton == MOUSE_LEFT) {
            // click on the element
            elm.click();  
          }
          else if (mouseButton == MOUSE_RIGHT) {
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.contextClick(elm);
            action.build().perform();
          }
          // release control keys (Ctrl, Alt, Shift, Meta)
          releaseControlKeys(combinedControlKeys);
          // successfully clicked on element, turn on the flag to escape the loop
          success = true;
        }
      } catch (Exception e) { 
        releaseControlKeys(combinedControlKeys);
        // probably the element is not present yet or it is non-clickable
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        // if element is found and we reached to the timeout, try to click on it with JavaScript
        if ((elm != null) && (timeSpentInMillis > timeoutInMillies)) {
          // press control keys (Ctrl, Alt, Shift, Meta), if any
          pressControlKeys(combinedControlKeys);
          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;
          js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm);
          releaseControlKeys(combinedControlKeys);
          // successfully clicked on element, turn on the flag to escape the loop
          success = true;
        }
      }
    }

    if (success) {
      // if element is <option> tag on Firefox browser,
      // perform a workaround to support MOUSE_LEFT
      if (isOptionTagOnFireFox)
      {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(300);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
      }
    }
    else { // failed
      if (elm == null) {
          throw new NoSuchElementException("Element not found.");
      } else {
          throw new Exception("Failed to click on the element");
      }
    }
  }

    public void sendKeys(By locator, String keys, boolean clearTextBeforeSendingKeys, int timeoutInSeconds) throws Exception {
    WebElement elm = findElement(locator, timeoutInSeconds);
    if (clearTextBeforeSendingKeys) elm.clear();
    elm.sendKeys(keys);
  }
```

The error

> invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated

start at

```
sendKeys(By.id("title"), "ttttt", true, 4);
```

I'm using Eclipse and ChromeDriver 2.27

Not sure why but the input field is visible. Can't move forward because of error. Any Idea how to solve this error?

Comment: Could you show these methods `sendKeys()` and `click()`???

Comment: Have you checked whether the input element is not disabled? Also, you should include the actual part of the HTML that you are trying to interact with. Perhaps this element is _changed_ via javascript?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I include the methods of `sendKeys()` and `click()` on the description. Please check again. Thank you.

Comment: @JChrist the element is not disabled. It's visible and nothing else.

Comment: @Evilfear Are you sure this line `elm.clear();` operating on `textbox` or `textarea` element??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur yes because I have other textbox and it's working properly. Not sure why not on that specific title textbox. It's strange actually.

Comment: @Evilfear this occurs only when `textbox` is in disable state, you need to wait until it's enable or try to click on it before clear it. Thanks..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur as I said to JChrist, the `textbox` is not disable state. I didn't disable the `textbox`. That's why on my code. click first before sendkeys. You can see it clearly.

Comment: Having issue with same 2 methods except in PhantomJS.